# MATLAB object property visible but not modifyable

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object

I want to have a property of an object be visible to the user, but not modifiable by the user. I've tried the following

```
classdef myObject < handle

    properties (Access = private, Hidden = false)
        property
    end
```

but this one remains hidden to the user, and I can't find anything in the documentation that would do this. Is there a way to make the property "read-only"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the `Access` property, there are also `GetAccess` and `SetAccess` properties. See [the documentation for these](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html).

```matlab
classdef myObject < handle

    properties (SetAccess = private)
        property
    end
```

Note that `Access` is a pseudo-property, a short-hand to set both `GetAccess` and `SetAccess` to the same value.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks.